# Does Audience Manager emit logging through logback?

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, outbound-email, audience-manager

Does anyone know if the Audience Manager API emits any logging information on the Content Delivery side (we're using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1)?

Is there a logger I can add to logback.xml?

```
<logger name="com.tridion.marketingsolution">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingAudienceManagerLog"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: All addons that use CD API's use logback (some more some less) whether they want it or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Elena's blog post](http://elenaserghie.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/sdl-tridion-2011-logs.html) this should be configurable in `logback.xml` and should output a file of the format `sync_audiencemanager.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log`

There is more information in the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_846D863B76CE4E83BD2FBC09A988FE32) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

```xml
<appender name="rollingAudiencemanagerLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/sync_audiencemanager.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
  </encoder>
  <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>


<logger name="com.tridion.marketingsolution">
  <appender-ref ref="rollingAudiencemanagerLog"/>
</logger>
```